# Have anyone a solution to send row parameter to a stored prodedure in MS-SQL Server with dynamic Column Arrangement?

Tags: sql-server, logging, parameter-passing, database-trigger

I Could write a trigger for a table that is able to detect updated columns and logs the changes. I want to make a stored procedure from this trigger and call it when required. But I do not know how can I send "inserted" or "updated" rows that are valid in trigger body, to this SP. 
Here is my trigger :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgr_MyTable_TransactionLogUpdate]
       ON  [dbo].[MyTable]
       AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN

    if (select F_SharhRadif from [Payeh.Decode] where F_ShJadval=18 and F_ShRadif=1)='2'
    begin
        return
    end

    declare @userid int=(select top 1 userid from inserted)
    declare @computername nvarchar(50)=(select top 1 computername from inserted)
    declare @ip nvarchar(50)=(select top 1 IP from inserted)
    declare @zamantaqeer datetime=(select top 1 F_ZamanTaqeer from inserted)
    declare @changetime =GETDATE()


    DECLARE @tableID        BIGINT=(SELECT id FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE [name]='MyTable')
    DECLARE @ColCount       INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE id=@tableID)
    DECLARE @ColIndex       INT=1
    DECLARE @UpdateDetails  NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @ColName        NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @ByteIndex      INT

    SELECT * INTO #d FROM deleted
    SELECT * INTO #i FROM inserted

    WHILE (@ColIndex<=@ColCount)
    BEGIN
        --IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED()&POWER(2,@ColIndex-1) <> 0)
        SET @ByteIndex=((@ColIndex-1)/8)+1
        IF (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@ByteIndex,1))&POWER(2,((@ColIndex-1)%8)) <> 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColName=(SELECT [name] FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE id=@tableID AND colid=@ColIndex)
            DECLARE @OldValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @NewValue NVARCHAR(MAX)

            DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(100)=N'@DeletedValue NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
            DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)='SELECT @DeletedValue=LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),'+@ColName+'))) FROM #d'
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@ParmDefinition,@DeletedValue=@OldValue OUTPUT

            SET @ParmDefinition = N'@InsertedValue NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
            SET @SQL= 'SELECT @InsertedValue=LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),'+@ColName+'))) FROM #i'
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@ParmDefinition,@InsertedValue=@NewValue OUTPUT
            IF (@OldValue<>@NewValue)
            BEGIN
                SET @UpdateDetails=@UpdateDetails+@ColName+': OLD="'+ @OldValue+'" -New="'+@NewValue+'", '
            END
        END
        SET @ColIndex=@ColIndex+1
    END

    IF (LEN(@UpdateDetails)>0)
    BEGIN   
        SET @UpdateDetails=SUBSTRING(@UpdateDetails,1,LEN(@UpdateDetails)-1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @UpdateDetails='No Changes'
    END

    --[User.TransactionLog] is the name of the table that stores the history of changes
    INSERT INTO [User.TransactionLog] 
        ([Tablename],[OperationType],[Desciption],[UserID],[ComputerName],[IP],[ChangeTime])
         SELECT 'MyTable',2,@UpdateDetails,'',@userid,@computername,@ip, @changetime

    DROP TABLE #d
    DROP TABLE #i
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Short answer is you can't. A trigger is called within a context that allows it to "know" which rows were affected. You would need to somehow define the set of rows of interest within your procedure. You should realize that your trigger has the very common logic flaw of assuming a single row is affected to the update (or merge) statement.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The way you are trying to audit data changes is less than ideal. You are wanting to insert a delimited list of changes into a single column. This means that your audit data is nearly worthless outside of a human looking at it. You can't query that without a lot of effort. But your table seems to have some interesting things already. It seems like you have columns with names of people.